# connection to selenium webdriver and airflow

Tags: selenium-webdriver, networking, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

so today i was trying to web scrape via apache-airflow but it is giving this error

```
  File "/home/siva/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/siva/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 105, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /d/apache-airflow/dags/chromedriver.exe
```

what should I do to connect the service so the web scrapping can be done I run my airflow test bench in ubuntu wsl so if there is any solution please provide it to get its work done in airflow
or if there are other ways to scrape in airflow do suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Can not connect to the Service /d/apache-airflow/dags/chromedriver.exe`

I don't have this set up to test with Airflow to be sure, but I have successfully run Chrome with Selenium under WSL2.

It sounds like you might be following some old instructions that were applicable for WSL1.  Under WSL1, my understanding is that it is possible to use the Windows Chrome executable/webdriver.

You might want to try switching to WSL1, but I don't know for sure that Airflow will run there.  It's very likely that it will.

However, if you do need to use WSL2, you'll have to use the Linux binaries.

This means that you'll need to [install Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9025903?hl=en) inside the WSL distribution and use the [corresponding `chromedriver_linux64.zip`](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

You'll also need to either ...

- ... be running WSL with the [ability to run graphical applications](https://superuser.com/a/1669770/1210833) - If you have Windows 11, this is automatic.  If not, I recommend Xrdp as the next easiest path.
- ... or run Chrome in headless mode.  I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do this with Airflow, unfortunately.